# How to customize color, font, background color, and alignment of WhatsApp share button which I created using html?

Tags: java, android, html, css

I'm coding WhatsApp share button on a webpage. However, I need to customize it with css code. Can anyone please share me the customization code. for this.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://vcard.scorexcreen.com/kiran-praveen">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

Comment: Use a library like fontawesome and any css library like bootstrap 4 to design your link. just call the approriate classes from the css libraries. something like `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>`.

Comment: @nelsonsule Thank you very much for your response. I don't know coding. I don't get plugin for that. So, I'm forced to code. Can you please give a code with center alignment , green background and WhatsApp icon before the text. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look to the guidelines of the usage of such shortcuts! It is not allowed to modify them. As they want to ensure that their icon looks the same on every page.

Comment: I don't need to customize WhatsApp icon look. I just wanted to add whatsapp icon before 'share on WhatsApp text' and want to customize background of text and alignment.

Comment: Then this question has nothing to do with whatsapp